# Is it possible to report on deleted activities/

Tags: activity, deleted

Is it possible to run a report on deleted activities? There's an is_deleted flag in the civicrm_activity table which isn't exposed by search kit and I can't find any is_deleted flags set to anything other than zero. And deleted activities do disappear from the above table. Would a logging table hold the deleted activities? it doesn't look like it, after trying out a delete on another site.  Civi is at 5.47.4 & Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2):

civicrm_activity.is_deleted is only used by civicase. Regular activities disappear. If you have logging at administer - system settings - misc turned on then log_civicrm_activity will have them where log_action = delete.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated, I can see the deletes in the log_civicrm_activity table  A pity that search kit doesn't allow searching the log table - guess I'll have to use Drupal Views if the user really does want a report

Comment: In theory you could see it with the CiviReport Contact Logging Summary, but that report is iffy for anything that isn't a Contact, and isn't good with activities.

Comment: So not highly recommended then!!

Comment: Maybe a separate question, but how to add a log.civicrm.xxx table to Drupal Views? I've addded it to settings.php, cleared caches but nothing doing.

Comment: I'd ask it as a separate question then the views experts will see it.